# Why do ping packets not reach a custom gateway in docker?

Tags: linux, networking, docker, icmp, linux-containers

## The Story

I have the following virtual Docker network configuration:

```
 ...10.2        ...10.3 ...100.3        ...100.2
+------+            +-------+            +------+
| so_A +--so_net_a--+ so_AB +--so_net_b--+ so_B |
+------+ ...10.0/24 +-------+ ..100.0/24 +------+
```

Build with the setup script in the end of the question. Here `so_A`, `so_AB` and `so_B` are Debian containers; `so_net_a` and `so_net_b` are Docker networks (a recently added feature).

I want to make a router out of the middle container `so_AB`. For that I replace the default gateway in `so_A` with the ip of `so_AB`:

```
docker exec --privileged so_A ip route del default
docker exec --privileged so_A ip route add default via $AB_A_IP dev eth0
```

Then I run `tcpdump` on `so_AB` (in an extra terminal window):

```
docker attach so_AB
/# tcpdump -i eth0 -n
```

and ping some addresses from `so_A`. I do not understand, why when I ping an IP address from a completely unrelevant network, e.g.:

```
docker attach so_A
/# ping 192.168.200.2
```

`so_AB` receives ICMP packets (although by some reason from the default gateway `192.168.10.1`, while I would expect them to come from the `so_A` ip `192.168.10.2`), bun when I ping any address from the `so_net_b` subnet, e.g.:

```
/# ping 192.168.100.15
```

`so_AB` receives only ARP requiets, like `ARP, Request who-has 192.168.10.3 tell 192.168.10.2, length 28`.

`ip route get` shows that `so_A` uses the `so_AB` as a first-hop for both addresses.

## Question

Why do the ping packets for the relevant IP addresses **not** reach the custom-set default gateway, while the non-relevant ones do?

## Setup

I use the latest Docker version: `1.9.1, build a34a1d5` on my 64bit ubuntu `14.04`.

Here is a setup script to reproduce the issue:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.10.0/24 so_net_a
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.100.0/24 so_net_b

# Network topology:
# +------+            +-------+            +------+
# | so_A +--so_net_a--+ so_AB +--so_net_b--+ so_B |
# +------+            +-------+            +------+

docker run -itd --name=so_A --net=so_net_a debian /bin/bash
docker run -itd --name=so_B --net=so_net_b debian /bin/bash
docker run -itd --name=so_AB --net=so_net_a debian /bin/bash
docker network connect so_net_b so_AB

docker exec so_AB sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y tcpdump'

AB_A_IP=`docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.so_net_a.IPAddress}}' so_AB`
B_IP=`docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.so_net_b.IPAddress}}' so_B`

# Change the default gateway to so_AB
docker exec --privileged so_A ip route del default
docker exec --privileged so_A ip route add default via $AB_A_IP dev eth0

# Normally should be 192.168.100.2
echo $B_IP
```

Comment: I just wondered... if AB is to work as a gateway, can you make sure packet forwarding is enabled? Something like `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` . Not sure if it has to be executed on the host, guest, or both.

Comment: @Sjlver, it is on on the host and all three clients.