# Linux Networking - Docker Container to Remote Host via Gateway without using route add?

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I'm struggling with a networking issue.

I have a Docker instance running on `172.17.0.14` with all the containers on the `172.18.0.0/24` network. With Vagrant you would do something like `sudo route add -net 172.18.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.17.0.14` to access the subnet.

However, when I run `route add` inside the container I get

> SIOCADDRT: Operation not permitted

What can I do? Is there anything like Socat? I don't want to add the NETCAP capability.

Answer (score 4):

You need the right permissions for this. Apparently, there are at least two ways do do that:

One from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440097/why-do-ping-packets-not-reach-a-custom-gateway-in-docker):

```
docker exec --privileged container ip route add default via 172.17.0.14 dev eth0
```

The other option is to expose the netns from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27403625/1705441):

```
pid=($sudo docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' container)

sudo mkdir -p /var/run/netns
sudo ln -s /proc/$pid/ns/net /var/run/netns/$pid

sudo ip netns exec $pid ip route add default via 172.17.0.14
```

Comment: It's worthy to mention that `--priviledged` is generally considered dangerous as it grants your docker container extra linux capabilities (e.g. CAP_SYS_ADMIN, etc.) that it would normally not have. It effectively disables most docker isolation features, hence keep in mind the environment where this would be used and it's level of trust.